# Regularity of weak solutions of an equation related to conformal maps

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, conformal-geometry

Let $\Omega\subset R^d$ be a nice bounded domain (say, the unit ball). Consider the following equation for $f:\Omega\to R^d$,
$$
\operatorname{div}((\det \nabla f)^{1-2/d} \nabla f) = 0.
$$
Suppose that $f\in W^{1,p}(\Omega;R^d)$, $p\ge 1$, is a weak solution of this equation. Is it automatically guaranteed to be a classical solution?

For $d=2$, this equation is nothing but the Laplace equation, so the answer is clearly positive.
I believe the answer to be positive for $d>2$ as well, since it is satisfied by conformal maps. The question is whether regularity can be (relatively easily) deduced from the structure of this equation?

Comment: For $d>2$, the equation is satisfied whenever det $\nabla f$=0. But det $\nabla f$=0 does not imply any regularity.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy You are right of course. I think a more interesting version of the question would be whether all weak solutions which are (almost everywhere) immersions, are strong.